# Split image by color using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to split this image by the gray color of each rectangle.

The idea is to return the coordinate of each corner so I can use it to process what is inside.

I am a OpenCV newbie so I would like to know what is the best approach to do this. Is `findContours` enough to get these coordinates or is there a better function for this?

Regards

[image]

Comment: Which corner are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simple to solve using `findContours`:

- Read input image as Grayscale (not as RGB).
- Apply threshold, and inverse polarity (make all gray pixel white, and background black).
- Find contours on threshold image.
- Find bounding rectangle of each contour.

The solution draws a green rectangle around each contour, for testing.

Here is a working code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read input image as Grayscale
img = cv2.imread('boxes.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Convert img to uint8 binary image with values 0 and 255
# All white pixels above 250 goes to 255, and other pixels goes to 0
ret, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(img, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Inverse polarity
thresh_gray = 255 - thresh_gray


# Find contours in thresh_gray.
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]  # [-2] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).

corners = []

# Iterate contours, find bounding rectangles, and add corners to a list
for c in contours:
    # Get bounding rectangle
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Append corner to list of corners - format is corners[i] holds a tuple: ((x0, y0), (x1, y1))
    corners.append(((x, y), (x+w, y+h)))

# Convert grayscale to BGR (just for testing - for drawing rectangles in green color).
out = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Draw green rectangle (for testing)
for c in corners:
    cv2.rectangle(out, c[0], c[1], (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)  #Save out to file (for testing).


# Show result (for testing).
cv2.imshow('out', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Result:
[image]

List of corners:

```
corners = [((491, 153), (523, 181)),
           ((24, 151), (68, 178)),
           ((231, 123), (277, 158)),
           ((442, 103), (488, 131)),
           ((7, 99), (76, 132)),
           ((211, 75), (285, 110)),
           ((268, 57), (269, 58)),
           ((420, 49), (494, 84)),
           ((5, 47), (58, 83)),
           ((213, 18), (267, 59)),
           ((420, 0), (477, 33))]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. I found another way to do it using scipy connected components and after getting all the labels, get the start and stop points for each box. Your solution looks cleaner though. Thank you